# JS generate table from multiples text areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to generate a (unique) table from multiple text areas. The Idea is to fill the 1st column from the 1st text area, the 2nd column from the 2nd text area and the same for the third one (but in the end, all the data needs to be part of the same table (in different rows).

Tried this script:

```
<script>
function generateTable() {
    var data = $('textarea[name=excel_data1]').val(); console.log(data);
    var rows = data.split("\n");
    var table = $('<table />');

for(var y in rows) {
    var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
    var row = $('<tr />');
    for(var x in cells) {
        row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
    }
    table.append(row);
}

$('#excel_table1').html(table);
}
</script>
```

That's my "body" with the text areas in divs:

```
  <div id=references>   <p>FI/ND:</p>
<textarea name="excel_data1" style="width:100px;height:20px;"></textarea> 
         </div>

  <div id=adresses>   <p>Adresses:</p>  
<textarea name="excel_data2" style="width:200px;height:20px;"></textarea>
         </div>

  <div id=more>   <p>(more:)</p>  
<textarea name="excel_data3" style="width:100px;height:20px;"></textarea>
         </div>
      <br>
<input id=bouton1 type="button" onclick="javascript:generateTable()" value="generate table"/>
```

And that's the table generated in a different body:

```
<p>Table:</p>
   <div id="excel_table1"></div>

</center></body>
```

It works perfectly from one text area but I can't make it work from multiple text areas.

Can Anyone help? thanks in advance :)

(sorry, I'm not an native English speaker)

P.S.: Tried copying the script twice, only changing the name of the textareas, but then the first textarea stop working:

```
<script>       
  function generateTable() {

    $('textarea[name=excel_data1]').each(function(){

      var data = $(this).val(); console.log(data);
      var rows = data.split("\n");
      var table = $('<table />');

        for(var y in rows) {
            var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
            var row = $('<tr />');
            for(var x in cells) {
                row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
            }
            table.append(row);
        }
        $('#excel_table1').html(table);

    })

}

function generateTable() {

    $('textarea[name=excel_data2]').each(function(){

      var data = $(this).val(); console.log(data);
      var rows = data.split("\n");
      var table = $('<table />');

        for(var y in rows) {
            var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
            var row = $('<tr />');
            for(var x in cells) {
                row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
            }
            table.append(row);
        }
        $('#excel_table1').html(table);

    })

}      
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to repeat what you are doing for all textareas, so you can have something like this:

```
function generateTable() {

    $('textarea').each(function(){

      var data = $(this).val(); console.log(data);
      var rows = data.split("\n");
      var table = $('<table />');

        for(var y in rows) {
            var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
            var row = $('<tr />');
            for(var x in cells) {
                row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
            }
            table.append(row);
        }   

        $('#excel_table1').append(table);    
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried that (copy/pasting your fonction twice, only changing the textarea name) but when I add the second text area, the first one stop working...

Comment: @EnjoyLifeJG You tried with `$('textarea[name=excel_data1]')`? That will ofcourse give only one result. I used `$('textarea')`, and that selects all textareas. Try to read the answer carefully and properly

Comment: Yes, I tried only using $('textarea'), but then, only the 3rd textarea was working (excel_data3). I don't get how am I supposed to "repeat what you are doing for all textareas" if I don't specify each textarea name.

Comment: @EnjoyLifeJG Try with `$('#excel_table1').append(table);` instead of `.html()` and use `$('textarea')` it selects all textarea elements even if you don't specify a name

Comment: Yes thank You, we're getting closer ! :D Now, All the text areas are in the table, but all in the same column instead of getting Textarea1=1st column   Textarea2=2nd Column

Comment: @EnjoyLifeJG Look now you know how to get all the values, try to do a console.log and see how you can add all data in tables like you want

Answer (score 0):

you should process in a different way.
For example :
1. loop on each text element (it is very simple with jQuery)
    - get the content
    - add the content in a rows ( tag)
2. build the final table and add where you want.

You can try this script :

```
<script>

var rows = "", table = "";
$("textarea").each(function (){
    rows += "<tr><td>"+$(this).val()+"</td></tr>";
});
table = "<table>"+rows+"</table>";
$('#excel_table1').html(table);

</script>
```